# How do I view all the "commands" for minecraft forge once I have it imported into my minecraft workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, static-libraries, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I started learning Java a while ago and I have a decent understanding of the language (I am about half way through Herbert Scheildns Java a beginners guide book).

I really wanted to code a MineCraft mod in forge. So I set up the environment using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tD6MsMWIH-4&list=UUrsaesoinvX126cv-ctAwBw&index=18 and it worked.

Now I sort of have two questions at this point. One is slightly off topic but I don't really know where else to ask and id appreciate the help. If you'd rather not answer the off topic question please at least help with the other one.

My first question is this: How do I view the "commands" for MineCraft forge. I know it imports a library of commands and I was wondering if there was a way to view them (commands like getHealth() or things like this) .

Now here is the off topic question: What is the best way for me to learn how to code with MineCraft forge. I know there is a specific "syntax" things have to have so a mod will run like proxies and Preload methods and things so I was wondering if there was some type of tutorial you all know about. Thanks for the help in advanced, sorry about going of topic!

Comment: Do you mean in-game commands?  Or the Java API?

Comment: Api, im trying to code a mod

Comment: Although, just a thing to know, the forge version i imported into eclipse was 1.7.10 recomended/latest(they are same build) and it was the src (ziped) version.

Comment: Remember that about 75% of the code you use is not part of Forge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of APIs for Forge by going to [files.minecraftforge.net](http://files.minecraftforge.net/), finding the version of Forge that you're using, and click on the JavaDoc link.

Once you've downloaded it, unzip to any directory, and open `Start.html`

There are some excellent tutorials listed on the [Forge forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php/board,120.0.html).  When I started out in 1.7 I found the Bedrock_Miner tutorial to be excellent and easy to follow.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ryan, that basically just answerd my first question! I apreciate it.

Comment: Ok! Thanks again Ryan! I wish i could upvote you but i dont quite have 15 rep yet, (new to this site) so ill come back and do it when i can.

Comment: @AshwinGupta As Alex K said above, you don't need to upvote.  If it's your question, you just need to accept one of the answers using the green checkmark under the vote arrows.